# Is an nth root of unity a square?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Suppose w^(2n)=1 (w is a complex number).
For which n (if any) \sqrt(w) \in Q(w) ?

Comment: Perhaps the title should say something about the field Q(w)... how about "Is root of unity w a square in Q(w)?"

Comment: This could be homework for a second course in number theory, but it also could be a lemma needed by someone in a field far from number theory. I would leave this open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key point is to understand the field Q(w) for w a primitive kth root of unity. Call this field Q<sub>k</sub>. In particular, you want to know that Q<sub>4n</sub> \neq Q<sub>2n</sub>.

The key fact here is that the field extension Q<sub>k</sub>/Q has degree phi(k), where phi(k) is the Euler phi function, and phi(4k) \neq phi(2k). For a proof that Q<sub>k</sub>/Q has degree phi(k), see the early parts of any book on cyclotomic fields. This is probably also done in many Galois theory books but I don't know which ones.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Yes I need this for some lemma.

Answer (score 1):

If w is a primitive 2n-th root, then the answer is "none".  If w is not primitive, then Q(w) has a square root of w if and only if and odd power of w is 1.

Comment: I want w to be a primitive 2n-th root. Can you give me a hint of how to prove the fact that you mentioned?